# How can I stop my cursor changing to a vertical arrow over text?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple `<div>` that is part of a grid area made up of other `<div>`'s  I allow the user to click and double click over the `<div>` area. A click changes a color of the `<div>` and a double click opens a modal window.

When the cursor hovers over text inside the `<div>` then it turns to a vertical bar.

How can I make it so that the cursor always shows as a pointing finger anywhere inside the `<div>`. Not sure if it makes a difference but I am looking for a solution for IE9 and above.

```
<div>
    <div>x</div>
    <div>y</div>
</div>
```

For example is there a way I could set the CSS on the outer `Div` so it makes all the inner `DIV`s have a pointer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can control the pointer using css [cursor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor) property, for example

```
div{
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/Srn79/)

Comment: How can I set this up so that the cursor changes to a pointer if there is a pointer class on the div?

Comment: I am getting a bit confused. If you don't mind could you give me a simple example that shows a couple of divs inside a div and the CSS where I could for example set the pointer on the outer div.

Comment: @TilwinJoy: As you have demonstrated in your last fiddle the `:hover` pseudoclass is unnecessary. Personally I think it is cleaner without it (since the non-hover situation makes no sense). At least worth noting anyway. :)

Answer (score -2):

If you render the text as an image that could work. Apple does this on their website.

Comment: Although this would technically work the drawbacks are quite significant such as not being able to search text, not being indexable by google, not responding to text resizing, not working with a screen reader (ie browsers for blind people), etc.

Comment: IMHO, worst advice ever.

Comment: @Terry: Try to use constructive criticism if you are going to say something like that. If you think its bad advice say why. If you think that my previous comment covered all the reasons so you don't think it is worth mentioning them then ask yourself whether your comment actually adds any value to this answer.

Comment: @Chris Sure, I'd be more than happy to enumerate them. Image-based texts are undesirable because (1) they cost more overhead and bandwidth compared to text; (2) do not compress well with gzip or other compression algorithms; (3) content is not visible to search engine bots; (4) compression artefacts if lossy compression is used; and huge overhead (see point 1) if lossless compression is used; (5) complicates workflow when updating site or content; (6) unable to style text dynamically via CSS; (7) bad accesssibility (screen readers are probably in capable of reading image-based texts).

Comment: @A.D. My directness may be unpleasant and appear to be uncalled for, but so are one-line answers that add little value to the discussion.

Comment: @Terry: Thanks. I believe that is much more appropriate as a comment and hopefully helps others learn something too (which is why we are here after all).